# Failure upgrading to jquery-ui v1.13.2 "accordian is not a function"

Tags: typescript, jquery-ui

I am using typescript and am trying to upgrade from jqueryui v1.11.1 to jquery-ui v1.13.2.

There seem to be known issues because the @types is still jqueryui, no hyphen. I have tried the solutions I can find and eventually got the code to compile but then I get a runtime error saying "accordian is not a function" suggesting that the module has not been loaded.

I added jquery-ui to the tsconfig and that allows me to use "import 'jquery-ui'" but I get the following compile error:

```
    ERROR in ../node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts 9:8
    Module parse failed: Unexpected token (9:8)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | /// <reference types="jquery" />
    |
    > declare namespace JQueryUI {
    |     // Accordion //////////////////////////////////////////////////
    |
    i ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

The suggested work around for this is to use `<reference>` in the file instead of import, that gets rid of the compile error but leaves me with a runtime error instead "accordion is not a function", there was a suggestion that this could be caused by the order of the import of jquery and jquery-ui so I also used reference for jquery but it made no difference.

Where I am now is:

```
In tsconfig.json I have 
    "compilerOptions": {
        "paths": {
            ...
            "jquery-ui":["node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts"]
        }
    }
```

I the tsx file I have

```
///<reference path="../../../../../../node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts"/>
///<reference path="../../../../../../node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts"/>
import $ from 'jquery';
```

Anyone know how I can fix the runtime error

Here are my versions

- jquery: 3.6.0
- @types/jquery: 3.3.29
- jquery-ui: 1.13.2
- @types/jqueryui: 1.12.16
- webpack: 4.33.0
- npm: 8.19.2
- node: 14.17.0

Thanks, Vincent